# Twilio video example js project not dsplaying video

Tags: twilio

I am trying to get the [Twilio video example js project](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js) to run.

If I add the env variables, run npm install, run npm start (I see in terminal that some files are being copied, and the message saying the express server is running on *:3000), and go to http://localhost:3000 clicking the preview camera button doesn't display any video in the preview video block. I click on the button and nothing gets logged to console or to terminal. I'm able to join / create rooms but there's no video. Any idea what could be the issue? I am on a mac, using chrome, and am working on the javascript video quickstart repo on github.

Comment: Can you check whether you've blocked access to video/microphone in Chrome for localhost:3000. There are instructions here: https://www.lifewire.com/configure-camera-microphone-setting-in-google-chrome-4103623

Answer (score 0):

ensure you have this in your codes, so you can see the log in the browser console.

var connectOptions = {
      name: roomName,
      logLevel: 'debug'
    };